# How to grep a array from nested array or nested object in Json using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, object, multidimensional-array

I am getting a result in JSON format where object can be inside object or array.On click of a function, take the value and find the object of that value and append the values

```
var result={  
"diagnosis":{  
  "Diagnosis":{  
     "head":"Diagnosis",
     "head_id":"18",
     "param":{  
        "10436":"Abortion",
        "10452":"Abscess",
     }
  },
  "ADR-ART":{  
     "head":"ADR-ART",
     "head_id":"19",
     "param":{  
        "120":"A K I",
        "66":"Abdominal Pain

     }
  },
  "ADR-Rx":{  
     "head":"ADR-Rx",
     "head_id":"20",
     "param":{  
        "66":"Abdominal Pain",
        "67":"Alopecia",
        "34":"Anaemia",
        "53":"Anorexia",
     }
  },

 },
 "examination":{  
  "General":{  
     "head":"General",
     "head_id":"8",
     "param":{
        "33":"Anemia",
        "27":"Apthous Ulcers",
        "35":"Ascitis",
     }
  },
  "Skin":{  
     "head":"Skin",
     "head_id":"9",
     "param":{  
        "14":"Alopecia \/ Hair Loss",
        "20":"Angular Cheilitis",
     }
  },
  "Oral":{  
     "head":"Oral",
     "head_id":"10",
```

I have a select dropdown of diagnosis,examination and so on.Suppose I select examination, then the object of examination should be extracted and its all head and head_id should be appended. This is what i have tried :

```
function change_category(objEleme){
var tab_value = $('#head_section_'+objEleme).val(); // value from 1st dropdown list eg : examination
$.each(result.tab_value, function(idx, data){
    console.log(data.head + ' ' + data.head_id);
});return false;
```

Expected output :

```
   <option value="8">General</option>
   <option value="9">Skin</option>
   <option value="10">Oral</option>
```

Comment: Use Bracket notation `result[tab_value]`

Comment: Thanks Satpal this worked. One more problem...How can i access param data of General (On function click i get head and head id) and output it for select dropdown ?

Comment: I found answer to my second question. I got the selected option text in a variable head and then did the following :
    $.each(result[tab_value][head]['param'], function(idx,data){
   //do something
  });

Answer (score 0):

Use `result[tab_value]` 
 and for the param only for "General" you have to simply use nested loop

```
$.each(result[tab_value], function(idx, data){
    console.log(data.head + ' ' + data.head_id);
    if(data.head == "General")
      { $.each(data.param, function(param_idx, param_data)  
         {
             // do something
         });
       }
 });
```